# Desired xorg.conf settings not effective on login

Tags: rhel, x11, display-settings

I've got a RHEL 8.6 station, with 2 NVIDIA graphic cards and 6 screens, configured with *nvidia-settings*.

- 5 screens are 19" screens with no rotation
- the other one is a 21" screen, rotated left

They all share *X screen 0* (*Enable base mosaic* is on).

I configure them to display 1280x1024 pixels: I force the resolution as desired, and for the vertical screen, I also set *ViewPortIn*, *ViewPortOut* and *Panning* to the same values. Once applied, the display looks exactly as desired and I save the corresponding *xorg.conf* file before logging out (or reboot).

The problem is that the settings are not properly restored on relogging. The content of *xorg.conf* is still the same, but the 5th screen active parameters become 1024x1280 for *ViewPortIn* and 1280x1280 for *Panning*.

Does anyone have an explanation of this, and a way to make the desired settings effective?
Many thanks in advance.